# How to make my Slack Bot reply as a thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I have a bot that's meant to reply to messages in a channel with certain keywords it's listening for. I have it deployed and it's working perfectly, but it replies in the channel rather than starting a thread to a user's message. Here's my code that's meant to start the thread:

```
app.message("ake up", async ({ command, say }) => {
  try {
    say({ text: "I'm awake! ⭐️ Do you need assistance?", thread_ts: message.ts });
  } catch (error) {
      console.log("err")
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Nothing happens when I send a message saying "wake up". When it's the same without `thread_ts: message.ts` and just says `say("I'm awake! ⭐️ Do you need assistance?")}`, it works perfectly. and responds with that.

Here's the beginning of my code for reference:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const app = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
  socketMode:true,
  appToken: process.env.APP_TOKEN
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This was [answered on GitHub](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/issues/1370#issuecomment-1075439234).

The trick here is that `thread_ts` is available only for threaded messages (it identifies the parent message which started the thread). If you want to start a thread, you can use `ts` value of the incoming message:

```js
app.message("ake up", async ({ message, say }) => {
  try {
      await say({ text: "I'm awake! ⭐️ Do you need assistance?" , thread_ts: message.thread_ts || message.ts});
  } catch (error) {
      console.log("err")
      console.error(error);
  }
});
```

See also [Spotting threads](https://api.slack.com/messaging/retrieving#finding_threads) guide in Slack docs.